# No config.inc.php file+ Class 'MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest' not Found

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I downloaded the Feeds API Section Client Library for php but there is no config.inc.php file. I even searched for the config file in other api library. Can anyone guide me through the problem??? To solve the issue, I created my own config.inc.php file and included the essential credentials, and made necessary changes in the SubmitFeedSample.php. But I am getting " Class 'MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest' not found" error. Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `config.inc.php` is actualy `.config.inc.php` and it is hidden as well.
And for `MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest` you need to `include` or `require_once` as below

```
require_once 'FeedsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Client.php';
require_once 'FeedsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Model/SubmitFeedRequest.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

The config.inc.php has a leading '.' (.config.inc.php) and it should be in the Samples directory.